# Rust shortest way to find the maximum product of a fixed length substring

Tags: rust, iterator

I'm trying to code in a Rust a function, that gives the maximum product of adjacent digits.

So given the string `123456789`, with 3 adjacent digits, the maximum is `7 * 8 * 9 = 504`.

I've tried to come up with this current functional solution (see previous edit for longer solutions). Could it be shortened? Comments are welcome.

The `log` is here, and desired, so the code runs quickly.

```rust
use std::iter::Map;
use std::str::Chars;

fn iter_log_digits(str: &str) -> Map<Chars<'_>, fn(char) -> f64> {
  str.chars().map(|c: char| (c.to_digit(10).unwrap() as f64).ln())
}

/// Returns the maximum log sum of adjacent digit characters.
/// # Arguments
/// - `str`: Assumes there are no 0s.
/// - `adj_count`: The number of adjacent digit characters.
fn max_adj_log_sum_no_zeros(str: &str, adj_count: usize) -> f64 {
  if str.len() < adj_count {
    return 0.;
  }
  let log_first: f64 = iter_log_digits(&str[..adj_count]).sum();
  iter_log_digits(&str).zip(iter_log_digits(&str[adj_count..])).fold(
    (log_first, log_first), // `(log_cur, log_max)`
    |(log_cur, log_max), (x_left, x_right)| {
      let log_next = log_cur - x_left + x_right;
      (log_next, log_max.max(log_next))
    }
  ).1
}

fn max_product_no_zeros(str: &str, adj_count: usize) -> u64 {
  max_adj_log_sum_no_zeros(str, adj_count).exp().round() as u64
}
```

`max_product_no_zeros("123456789", 3)` should return 504.

Comment: You're returning (approximately) `(504.0).ln()`, that is, roughly 6.222, not `504`. What's the actual spec here?

Comment: @trentcl Ah forgot to add `as u64`, that should fix it.

Comment: Not what I was objecting to. `504` is not the same number as `6.222576268071368`

Comment: @trentcl Did you run `max_adj_log_sum_no_zeros("123456789", 3).exp().round() as u64`?

Comment: You said: "I'm trying to code in a Rust a function, that gives the maximum product of adjacent digits." But the function you wrote doesn't do that.

Comment: @trentcl It just takes the log, which is easier. It is trivial to just add `.exp().round() as u64` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General observations:

- An indentation of two spaces is quite small.  The standard formatting uses four spaces.
- Names like `Map` and `Chars` read better with their modules: `iter::Map`, `str::Chars`.
- `str: &str` — don't do that.
- When `str` is not entirely made of decimal digits, your function panics by `unwrap`ping.  Reporting an error via `Result` is generally preferred.  Magic also happens when `str` contains zeros.
- Using `fold` here makes the semantics harder to understand.  A simple `for` loop might be more suitable.

---

Now, my intuition tells me floating point calculations are less efficient than just doing the operations on integers, so I wrote a benchmark.  Here's the result that I got:

```
running 4 tests
test l_f::tests::test ... ignored
test simonzack::tests::test ... ignored
test l_f::tests::bench       ... bench:  10,189,230 ns/iter (+/- 278,958)
test simonzack::tests::bench ... bench:  16,865,990 ns/iter (+/- 440,350)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 2 ignored; 2 measured; 0 filtered out
```

Using integers resulted in a ~1.7x speedup.  Do note that this benchmark is very crude, and you might want to measure your own use cases.

---

For reference, here's the code for the benchmark.  (Error checking is omitted for simplicity.)

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

mod l_f {
    fn to_digits(digits: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = u64> + '_ {
        digits.chars().map(|c| c.to_digit(10).unwrap().into())
    }

    pub fn max_product_no_zeros(digits: &str, length: usize) -> u64 {
        if digits.len() < length {
            return 0;
        }

        let mut current_product: u64 = to_digits(&digits[..length]).product();
        let mut max_product = current_product;

        for (left, right) in to_digits(digits).zip(to_digits(&digits[length..])) {
            current_product = current_product / left * right;
            max_product = max_product.max(current_product);
        }

        max_product
    }

    #[cfg(test)]
    mod tests {
        use test::Bencher;

        #[test]
        fn test() {
            assert_eq!(super::max_product_no_zeros("31415926", 3), 108);
        }

        #[bench]
        fn bench(b: &mut Bencher) {
            let digits = test::black_box("9".repeat(1_000_000));

            b.iter(|| super::max_product_no_zeros(&digits, 10));
        }
    }
}

mod simonzack {
    use std::iter::Map;
    use std::str::Chars;

    fn iter_log_digits(str: &str) -> Map<Chars<'_>, fn(char) -> f64> {
        str.chars()
            .map(|c: char| (c.to_digit(10).unwrap() as f64).ln())
    }

    /// Returns the maximum log sum of adjacent digit characters.
    /// # Arguments
    /// - `str`: Assumes there are no 0s.
    /// - `adj_count`: The number of adjacent digit characters.
    fn max_adj_log_sum_no_zeros(str: &str, adj_count: usize) -> f64 {
        if str.len() < adj_count {
            return 0.;
        }
        let log_first: f64 = iter_log_digits(&str[..adj_count]).sum();
        iter_log_digits(&str)
            .zip(iter_log_digits(&str[adj_count..]))
            .fold(
                (log_first, log_first), // `(log_cur, log_max)`
                |(log_cur, log_max), (x_left, x_right)| {
                    let log_next = log_cur - x_left + x_right;
                    (log_next, log_max.max(log_next))
                },
            )
            .1
    }

    pub fn max_product_no_zeros(str: &str, adj_count: usize) -> u64 {
        max_adj_log_sum_no_zeros(str, adj_count).exp().round() as u64
    }

    #[cfg(test)]
    mod tests {
        use test::Bencher;

        #[test]
        fn test() {
            assert_eq!(super::max_product_no_zeros("31415926", 3), 108);
        }

        #[bench]
        fn bench(b: &mut Bencher) {
            let digits = test::black_box("9".repeat(1_000_000));

            b.iter(|| super::max_product_no_zeros(&digits, 10));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark, it helped and I realized there's no point in the logs, as I need to store the result in an `u64` anyway at the end. I ended up just using `.scan()` and `.max()` after discovering the `.scan()` method.

Comment: @simonzack Indeed, `scan` method seems the most appropriate here.  I missed it when writing the benchmark.